# How to have a horizontal scroll work in website with the scroll width set to 0?

Tags: html, css

I want the user to be able to scroll in the web view like they can drag to scroll on mobile

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-meninsky-3d5r04?file=/index.html

I have created this sandbox and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      gap: 100px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    .wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 1</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 2</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 3</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 4</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 5</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 6</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 7</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 8</div>
      <div style="width: 50px;">box 9</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically I set the   `overflow: scroll;` and set the scroll bar width to inside `wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar`
[image]

---

But is there any way to make it scroll on the web as it does in the mobile view with a drag?

I just want my horizontal UI to be neat and clean without a scroll bar but I can't have it be draggable in the web

I think netflix had navigation arrows in their web app. Is it the only way to create a horizontal scroll UI in web?

Comment: you misusing a lot of terms here. `web` is not an appropriate term for `non-touch devices`! Mobile browsers (touch devices)  work the very same way on the web as non-touch devices. For latter the scrolling feature works still with the mousewheel. But for accessibility, removing a scrollbar is a bad approach to start with. Mire appropriate would be the use of `media queries` to only remove it on touch-devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users with a mouse (as is typical with users on desktop) you can scroll horizontally without scrollbars if you have a mouse wheel – you hover over the scrollable element, hold `shift` and then scroll on the mouse wheel.

If you would like to emulate touch-screen drag scrolling, you would need to use JavaScript, something like this:

```js
let pointerFrom = 0;
let elementFrom = 0;

const scrollable = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

const onDrag = (event) => {
  // Ensure we only do this for pointers that don't have native
  // drag-scrolling behavior and when the pointer is down.
  if (event.pointerType == 'mouse') {
    scrollable.scrollLeft = elementFrom - event.clientX + pointerFrom;
  }
};

scrollable.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {
  // Ensure we only do this for pointers that don't have native
  // drag-scrolling behavior.
  if (event.pointerType == 'mouse') {
    pointerDown = true;
    // Set the position where the mouse is starting to drag from.
    pointerFrom = event.clientX;
    // Set the position of the element is scrolled from.
    elementFrom = scrollable.scrollLeft;

    // React on pointer move.
    document.addEventListener('pointermove', onDrag);
  }
});

// Stop reacting on pointer move when pointer is no longer clicked.
document.addEventListener('pointerup', (event) => {
  // Ensure we only do this for pointers that don't have native
  // drag-scrolling behavior.
  if (event.pointerType == 'mouse') {
    document.removeEventListener('pointermove', onDrag);
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 1</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 2</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 3</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 4</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 5</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 6</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 7</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 8</div>
  <div style="width: 50px;">box 9</div>
</div>
```

With a mouse, there is some conflicting behavior; dragging with the left mouse button held down normally selects text, so you may need to resolve this conflict with extra code.